# Regex for matching curly braces

Tags: .net, regex, vb.net

I'm, looking for a regular expression that will match only when all curly braces properly match.  Matching braces can be nested.

Ex.
Matches

- Hello {0}{}
- Hello to the following {0}: {{Object1}}, {{Object2}}
- Test { {1} { {2} { {3} { {4}}}}}

Non-matches

- }{Hello {0}
- {{}Hello to the following {0}: {{Object1}}, {{Object2}}
- Test { {1} { {2} { {3} { {4}{}

Comment: In what language?  Most languages don't support nested regex matching, so you need to do this with a set of functions.

Comment: @wolffer-east: I'm doing it in VB.  I hoped though that it could be solved using pure Regular Expression syntax.  When you say 'most', does that imply that some do?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can regular expressions be used to match nested patterns?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/133601/can-regular-expressions-be-used-to-match-nested-patterns)

Comment: Just count all the { and all the } and make sure the count is the same.

Comment: @Derek: The first Non-matching example would pass in that case.  Not good.

Comment: @JeremyFriesen looks like .NET might have the ability, though I haven't used it myself: http://www.regular-expressions.info/balancing.html

Comment: Why don't you compare the count of `{` and `}` and then evaluate potentially valid strings with this expression: `/^[^}]*\{?/` (which will look for an optional `{` without any `}` before it).

Comment: I'm thinking you iterate character by character keeping a count of open and closed.  If numClosed is ever greater than numOpen return false.  At the end return ( numClosed == numOpen )

Comment: I have used a function that matches until an opening, then matches until another opening or closing bracket, keeping track of the depth.  every time it finds an opening item depth goes up one, every time a close it goes down.  if depth ever hits -1 it breaks, and if at the end depth is 0 then you have a correctly formatted string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In .NET you can use [balancing groups](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bs2twtah(v=vs.110).aspx#balancing_group_definition) to count, which allows you to solve such problems.

For example make sure `{` and `}` are balanced you could use an expression like:

```
(?x)^
[^{}]*
(?: 
  (?:
    (?'open' \{ )       # open++
    [^{}]*
  )+
  (?:
    (?'close-open' \} ) # open--, only if open > 0
    [^{}]*
  )+
)*
(?(open) (?!) )         # fail if open != 0
$
```

Comment: Here are a couple of more similar examples: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15752778/regex-w-balancing-group-that-matches-not-only-the-outmost-matches/15753431#15753431 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17003667/match-text-surrounded-by-and/17003704#17003704

Comment: Awesome! thanks, I just tested this against my exampples and it passed with flying colours.  Simply amazing.  I don't understand one bit of it, so I guess I have some reading to do!

Answer (score 2):

```
bool BracesMatch( string s )
{
  int numOpen = 0, numClosed = 0;
  foreach( char c in s.ToCharArray() )
  {
     if ( c == '{' ) numOpen++;
     if ( c == '}' ) numClosed++;
     if ( numClosed > numOpen ) return false;
  }
  return numOpen == numClosed;
}
```

Comment: Did you see this?  "if ( numClosed > numOpen ) return false;"

Comment: @Tensibai he checks `if ( numClosed > numOpen ) return false` on each character, so your example doesn't pass: http://ideone.com/JUkyLZ

Answer (score 1):

This might work using the Dot-Net balanced groups as well.

```
 # @"^[^{}]*(?:\{(?>[^{}]+|\{(?<Depth>)|\}(?<-Depth>))*(?(Depth)(?!))\}[^{}]*)*[^{}]*$"

 ^ 
 [^{}]*                        # Anything (but only if we're not at the start of { or } )
 (?:
      \{                            # Match opening {
      (?>                           # Then either match (possessively):
           [^{}]+                        #   Anything (but only if we're not at the start of { or } )
        |                              # or
           \{                            #  { (and increase the braces counter)
           (?<Depth> )
        |                              # or
           \}                            #  } (and decrease the braces counter).
           (?<-Depth> )
      )*                            # Repeat as needed.
      (?(Depth)                     # Assert that the braces counter is at zero.
           (?!)                          # Fail this part if depth > 0
      )
      \}                            # Then match a closing }. 
      [^{}]*                        # Anything (but only if we're not at the start of { or } )
 )*                            # Repeat as needed
 [^{}]*                        # Anything (but only if we're not at the start of { or } )
 $
```